# Why is this function youWin not working properly?

Tags: javascript, function, comparison-operators

I believe I'm posting all of the relevant code here.

The function definitely does run because if I switch the `>` to a `<` it gives me the alert when I click on the `'moveup'` button.
Also, the console logs that `pic2` continues to grow with each increment and `pic3` stays the same. So that part is working.

Something in the function just isn't comparing the two variables properly and I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
var player = document.getElementById("pic2").offsetLeft;
var finish = document.getElementById("pic3").offsetLeft;

console.log(player);
console.log(finish);

function youWin() {
  if (player >= finish) {
    alert("You Win!");
  } else {

  }
};

$(function() {
  $('#moveup').click(function() {
    $("#pic2").css('margin-left', '+=2vw');
    $("#pic3").css('margin-left', '-=2vw');
    document.getElementById("guessField").value = "";
    $('#myModalTrue').toggle();
    y = regenerate();
    var player = document.getElementById("pic2").offsetLeft;
    var finish = document.getElementById("pic3").offsetLeft;
    console.log(player);
    console.log(finish);
    youWin();
  });
});
```

Comment: Try logging values inside the ``youWin`` function it should return old values and your answer.

Comment: because of scoping of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you aren't changing the global `player` and `finish` variable. you are making new local ones. for more information about [variable scope in javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). try this

```
var player = document.getElementById("pic2").offsetLeft;
var finish = document.getElementById("pic3").offsetLeft;

console.log(player);
console.log(finish);

function youWin() {
  if (player >= finish) {
    alert("You Win!");
  } else {

  }
};
$(function() {
  $('#moveup').click(function() {
    $("#pic2").css('margin-left', '+=2vw');
    $("#pic3").css('margin-left', '-=2vw');
    document.getElementById("guessField").value = "";
    $('#myModalTrue').toggle();
    y = regenerate();
    player = document.getElementById("pic2").offsetLeft;//change is here
    finish = document.getElementById("pic3").offsetLeft;//and here
    console.log(player);
    console.log(finish);
    youWin();
  });
});
```

Comment: Preciate ya! It didn’t work but the solution of putting player and finish inside the function did the trick.  This is an awesome community. Thanks!!!

Comment: @JustinPaoletta impossible it should work. I made a jsfiddle with the same logic to be sure http://jsfiddle.net/4sv20pag/

Comment: Not sure what that comment is referring too @evgenifotia. My original comment was when your answer said *"try this"*

Comment: Yeah actually I think I messed something up... I’m reading through it again... thanks for the example!

Comment: My apologies! I’m trying to work and figure out personal coding problems.. your solution is working for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try logging values inside the `youWin` function it should return old values and your answer. Your `player` and `finish` values are not updating for function. It is still getting old values.

```
function youWin(player, finish) {
  if (player >= finish) {
    alert("You Win!");
  } else {

  }
};

$(function() {
  $('#moveup').click(function() {
    $("#pic2").css('margin-left', '+=2vw');
    $("#pic3").css('margin-left', '-=2vw');
    document.getElementById("guessField").value = "";
    $('#myModalTrue').toggle();
    y = regenerate();
    var player = document.getElementById("pic2").offsetLeft;
    var finish = document.getElementById("pic3").offsetLeft;
    console.log(player);
    console.log(finish);
    youWin(player, finish);
  });
});
```